# How to resolve Cannot read property 'timepicker' of undefined error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to implement the Jquery datetime picker on web page but keep getting the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timepicker' of undefined

I downloaded the timepicker add on from here:

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#basic_examples

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

Here is the section of the code generating the error:

```
$.ui.timepicker = $.ui.timepicker || {};
if ($.ui.timepicker.version) {
    return;
}
```

On my web page I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-lib/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="/Content/bootstrap/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/Content/bootstrap/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="/Content/bootstrap/js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
```

And script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datetimepicker").datepicker();
    });
```

Comment: You didn't import the main jQuery lib <.<

Comment: I did. I just edited the question:

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timepicker' of undefined means that

```
$.ui
```

is undefined. So, you probably have not included jQuery UI. Try to include it before any of your scripts (except jQuery itself).

Answer (score 0):

You'll also have to import the jQuery lib to use jQuery plugins. Throw this script before the rest:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```